# Optimize a recursive function in Julia

Tags: performance, recursion, julia

I wrote a Julia code which computes integrals over Gaussian functions and I have a sort-of kernel function which is called over and over again.
According to the Julia built-in `Profile` Module, this is where I spend most of the time during the actual computation and therefore I would like to see if there is any way in which I can improve it.

It is a recursive function and I implemented it in a kind of straightforward way. As I am not that much used to recursive functions, maybe somebody out there has some ideas/suggestions on how to improve it (both from a purely theoretical algorithmic point of view and/or exploiting special optimizations from the JIT compiler).

Here you have it:

```
"""Returns the integral of an Hermite Gaussian divided by the Coulomb operator."""
function Rtuv{T<:Real}(t::Int, u::Int, v::Int, n::Int, p::Real, RPC::Vector{T})
    if t == u == v == 0
        return (-2.0*p)^n * boys(n,p*norm(RPC)^2)
    elseif u == v == 0
        if t > 1
            return  (t-1)*Rtuv(t-2, u, v, n+1, p, RPC) +
                   RPC[1]*Rtuv(t-1, u, v, n+1, p, RPC)
        else
            return RPC[1]*Rtuv(t-1, u, v, n+1, p, RPC)
        end
    elseif v == 0
        if u > 1
            return  (u-1)*Rtuv(t, u-2, v, n+1, p, RPC) +
                   RPC[2]*Rtuv(t, u-1, v, n+1, p, RPC)
        else
            return RPC[2]*Rtuv(t, u-1, v, n+1, p ,RPC)
        end
    else
        if v > 1
            return  (v-1)*Rtuv(t, u, v-2, n+1, p, RPC)
                   RPC[3]*Rtuv(t, u, v-1, n+1, p, RPC)
        else
            return RPC[3]*Rtuv(t, u, v-1, n+1, p, RPC)
        end
    end
end
```

Don't pay that much attention to the function `boys`, since according to the profiler it is not that heavy.
Just to give an idea of the range of numbers: usually the first call comes from `t+u+v` ranging from `0` to `3`, while `n` always starts at `0`.

Cheers

### EDIT -- New information

<s>The generated version is slower for small values of `t,u,v`, I believe the reason is because expressions are not optimzied by the compiler.</s>
I was benchmarking badly for this case, without interpolating the argument passed. By doing it properly I am always faster with the approach explained in the accepted answer, so hurray!

More generally, does the compiler identify trivial cases such as multiplication by zeros and ones and optimize those away?

Answer to myself: from a quick checking of simple code with `@code_llvm` it seems not to be the case.

Comment: This is not fully relevant, but if you're a newcomer to recursive functions you might want to check out memoisation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization. This might not be straightforward to your case as you have multiple arguments, but could help you speed up your code by a lot.

Comment: I am not so sure that this applies to my case, because in general, for each _initiating_ call of `Rtuv`, the input variables `p` and `RPC` will be different and every recursive call inside the function body will also be different since `t,u,v,n` change.
On the other hand, if I have several _initiating_ calls with the same `p` and `RPC`, then I think memoization might be useful, though I don't if it's worth the effort.

Comment: I think there's something lost in the case for `v > 1` -- is there actually a nested recursion? And are `t, u, v` statically known? In that case, macro expansion could help.

Comment: Yes, somehow I copied and paste badly for `v > 1`, I now edited the code.
Yes there is a nested recursion, no, `t, u, v` are not statically known (if I understood what you meant..).
In general, this function get called inside a triple-nested loop over `t, u, v`, where their value (of `t, u, v`) is always assumed non-negative (I forgot to mention that before) and generally the each loop goes from `0` to `3` or `4`.

Regarding my previous comment in reply to @niczky12, actually memoization is quite easy to implement, I'm gonna give it a try and see if it improves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works in your case: you can "memoize" whole compiled methods using generated functions and get rid of all recursion after the first call.

Since `t`, `u`, and `v` will stay small, you could generate the fully expanded code for the recursions.  Assume for the simplicity a bogus implementation of

```
boys(n::Int, x::Real) = n + x
```

Then

```
function Rtuv_expr(t::Int, u::Int, v::Int, n, p, RPC)
    ninc = :($n + 1)

    if t == u == v == 0
        :((-2.0 * $p)^$n * boys($n, $p * norm($RPC)^2))
    elseif u == v == 0
        if t > 1
            :($(t-1) * $(Rtuv_expr(t-2, u, v, ninc, p, RPC)) +
              $RPC[1] * $(Rtuv_expr(t-1, u, v, ninc, p, RPC)))
        else
            :($RPC[1] * $(Rtuv_expr(t-1, u, v, ninc, p, RPC)))
        end
    elseif v == 0
        if u > 1
            :($(u-1) * $(Rtuv_expr(t, u-2, v, ninc, p, RPC)) +
              $RPC[2] * $(Rtuv_expr(t, u-1, v, ninc, p, RPC)))
        else
            :($RPC[2] * $(Rtuv_expr(t, u-1, v, ninc, p, RPC)))
        end
    else
        if v > 1 
            :($(v-1) * $(Rtuv_expr(t, u, v-2, ninc, p, RPC)) + 
              $RPC[3] * $(Rtuv_expr(t, u, v-1, ninc, p, RPC)))
        else
            :($RPC[3] * $(Rtuv_expr(t, u, v-1, ninc, p, RPC)))
        end
    end
end
```

will generate you fully expanded expressions like this:

```
julia> Rtuv_expr(1, 2, 1, 0, 0.1, rand(3))
:(([0.868194, 0.928591, 0.295344])[3] * (1 * (([0.868194, 0.928591, 0.295344])[1] * ((-2.0 * 0.1) ^ (((0 + 1) + 1) + 1) * boys(((0 + 1) + 1) + 1, 0.1 * norm([0.868194, 0.928591, 0.295344]) ^ 2))) + ([0.868194, 0.928591, 0.295344])[2] * (([0.868194, 0.928591, 0.295344])[2] * (([0.868194, 0.928591, 0.295344])[1] * ((-2.0 * 0.1) ^ ((((0 + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) * boys((((0 + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1, 0.1 * norm([0.868194, 0.928591, 0.295344]) ^ 2))))))
```

We can stuff that into a [generated function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/#Generated-functions-1) `Rtuv` taking `Val` types.  For each different combination of `T`, `U`, and `V`, this function will use `Rtuv_expr` to compile the respective expression and from then on use this method -- no recursion anymore:

```
@generated function Rtuv{T, U, V, X<:Real}(::Type{Val{T}}, ::Type{Val{U}}, ::Type{Val{V}},
                                           n::Int, p::Real, RPC::Vector{X})
    Rtuv_expr(T, U, V, :n, :p, :RPC)
end
```

You have to call it with `t`, `u`, `v` wrapped in `Val`, though:

```
julia> Rtuv(Val{1}, Val{2}, Val{1}, 0, 0.1, rand(3))
-0.0007782250832001092
```

If you test a small loop like this,

```
for t = 0:3, u = 0:3, v = 0:3
    println(Rtuv(Val{t}, Val{u}, Val{v}, 0, 0.1, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]))
end
```

it will need some time for the first run, but then go pretty fast, since the used methods are already compiled.

Comment: This seems very interesting, although quite advanced. I am taking my time to understand what's going on exactly by simplifying the above example with the simple fibonacci recursion.
However, to start with, am I understanding correctly that at the first run I will generate different `Rtuv` functions based on the actual integer value of `T, U, V` ? Then, I can feed any arbitrary `n, p, RPC` values to a given `Rtuv{T,U,V,X}` function? And that `Rtuv{T,U,V,X}` function is actually a fully expanded version (thanks to `Rtuv_expr`) in which actually no recursion happens anymore?

Comment: A fully expanded _and compiled_ method of the function `Rtuv` for each combination of `T`, `U` and `V`, yes. Since you said that these values are only small, and each method is used often as a kernel, I thought that might improve things.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am still a bit confused, so I tried to understand everything with a simpler example (which is however in principle equal to this problem), and I created a new independent post as it is quite general. You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51208693/7946478

Comment: I'll see if I can answer that question, but for a starter, here's a nice intro into the topic from JuliaCon 2015: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAN8zbM659o

Comment: I have watched it, although I haven't found it so clear, this and the (other discussion)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208693/optimizing-a-recursive-function-with-metaprogramming-in-julia] were more insightful. Anyway, I tested the _metaprogrammed_ implementation and it is faster for values of `t+u+v >= 4`, I have not done any real-case scenario benchmark though. I will see how that goes.
In the meantime I have another question, the `boys` function that I said not to care at the beginning is actually a call to the `GSL` library, can that be limiting in some way for this approach?

Comment: I don't think that the implementation of `boys` will matter. It is used only in the base case, and only called on values that are not recursed over.

Comment: I have done some more testing and sadly this approach is substantially slower in real-case scenarios. The reason is that most of the time I am calling the function with small values for `t,u,v` and in those cases the recursive definition is faster. However, I think I identified the problem, I edited my first post.